# How to implement pytesseract code with opencl to make it run on GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, opencl, data-science, tesseract, python-tesseract

I ran OCR on a document using *pytesseract*. Results were very good but it took a very long time.

Now I would like to run that code on GPU. The official *tesseract* documentation says that we can run code on GPU using *opencl* but I haven't found any implementation till now. Can anyone please explain how should I proceed?

Answer (score 4):

Where the official tesseract documentation **says** that *we can run code on GPU using opencl*? There is experimental and unsupported implementation of opencl for small part of code, but it does not do any significant improvement.

If you are interested in speed improvement, that have a look at [possibilities](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/263#issuecomment-536197289)  to run tesseract faster + use tesseract wrapper (or write your own - [see SimpleTesseractPythonWrapper](https://github.com/zdenop/SimpleTesseractPythonWrapper/blob/master/SimpleTesseractPythonWrapper.ipynb) ) that use its API instead of wrapping tesseract executable (e.g pytesseract).